# Square brackets in (nested) C structures

Tags: c

This could sound very basic but I would like to know what the square brackets represent in a C code like this. I do not have information about the types of the structure elements for structure "aaa" and I am trying to understand it from the code. Does it have to necessarily represent array indexing or it can be different things related to structures?

I understood it like this: "->" means that gindex is an element of structure aaa, then the bracket and then parameter is an element of whatever bracket represents and then again the square bracket.

```
aaa->gindex[aaa->elp_pos].parameter[aaa->no_elp] = sin->obs[counter1].typ_enu;
```

Comment: You'll want to re-read the section of your textbook that describes **arrays**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Square brackets are array indexing operators.

Based on that expression, the following must be true:

- `aaa` is a pointer to some struct type, we'll call it `struct A`.
- `struct A` contains at least the following members: `gindex`, `elp_pos`, and `no_elp`.
- `gindex` is an array of or pointer to another `struct` type, we'll call it `struct B`.
- `elp_pos` and `no_elp` are used as array indices, so they must have some integral type *`I`*.
- `struct B` contains at least the member `parameter`, which is an array of or pointer to some type *`T`*.
- `sin` is a pointer to some struct type, we'll call it `struct C`.
- `struct C` contains at least the member `obs`.
- `obs` is an array of or pointer to some `struct` type, we'll call it `struct D`.
- `struct D` contains at least the member `type_enu`, which is either the same type *`T`* as the `parameter` array in `struct B`, or a type compatible with *`T`*.
- `counter1` is used as an array index, so it must have some integral type *`I`*.

Thus, our types look something like the following:

```
struct D 
{
  ... 
  T type_enu;
  ...
};

struct C
{
  ...
  struct D obs[N]; // or struct D *obs;
  ...
};

struct B
{
  ...
  T parameter[N]; // or T *parameter;
  ...
};

struct A
{
  ...
  I elp_pos;
  I no_elp;
  struct B gindex[N]; // or struct B *gindex
  ...
};

struct A *aaa;
struct C *sin;
I counter1;
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Square brackets are the array indexing operator.

Essentially for any pointer `p` and integer index `i`, `p[i]` is the same as `*(p + i)`. It de-references the indexed element, indexing from the base at `p`.

This has nothing to do with the fact that the arrays are in structures to which you also have pointers.

So `gindex` is an array of structures in some structure to which you have a pointer named `aaa`. The element at index `aaa->elp_pos` is de-referenced, and that structure's `parameter` array's element at index `aaa->no_elp` is assigned to.

It's a complex line of code, but it's not doing anything complicated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets in expressions are used to index into arrays. For example...

```
int my_array[10];
my_array[0]=68;
```

In your example `gindex`, `parameter` and `obs` are all arrays of some unknown type. The only thing we can tell about them, is that they're not arrays of pointers as their elements are accessed with "." rather than "->"

Answer (score 0):

In C, Square Brackets are the array indexing operator.

For exemple take a **char *str** which is a pointer on a string.

If you want to print the "n" character of this string you need to do it

> String:

```
char *str = "Hello World";
```

> You want to print the "W" so you have to do it:

```
print("%c", str[6]);
```